# htaccess Redirect - Old Domain to New Domain with Slight Change in link structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm stuck. I don't know much about htaccess and I'm just winging it. Can someone look at the code and tell me what's wrong with it. I simply want to redirect an old site to a new site and the only changes are the domain, a variable that will match between old/new pages and an added word to the permalink structure.

Here's some of the variations I've tried so far:

```
Options +FolowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com/matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/matchingword1-$1-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/ [R=301,L]

Options +FolowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com/matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/matchingword1-%1-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^domain\.com/matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/$ http://www.newdomain.com/matchingword1-\$1-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/\ [R=301? [R=301,NE,NC]
```

The section (. *) will be the exact same as $1 on the new domain but the permalink is a little different. The part of the permalink that is (. *) will be anything from multiple words and numbers.

For example: matchingword1-this-page-is-1st-matchingword2-matchingword3/ redirects to newdomain dot com/matchingword1-this-page-is-1st-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite condition for `HTTP_HOST` is what is passed in the request's "Host:" header, which only contains the host (and in some cases a port). The Request URI isn't part of `HTTP_HOST`. Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/ http://www.newdomain.com/matchingword1-$1-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/ [R=301,L]
```

The last set doesn't look like it'll work at all.

Edit: comments won't let me insert code

If you want to redirect EVERYTHING, you should use mod_alias' RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1
```

If you are serving the directory on the same instance of apache (as in, domain.com and newdomain.com is actually the same server serving from the same directory), then you need to rewrite. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Seems like it might be closer but this is what I got when I tried one of the links:

Not Found

The requested URL (PAGE URL FROM OLD DOMAIN) was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I put in just the old domain name it takes me to the basic index page for the old domain.

Comment: This won't redirect everything to newdomain.com, it will ONLY redirect URL's that look like this: http://domain.com/matchingword1-BLAHBLAH-matchingword2-matchingword3/  if you want to redirect EVERYTHING, then you can just use a `RedirectMatch`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Comment: All the URLs on the old domain match the new domain except for the added word to the link.  I wasn't thinking when I setup the new site and should have just left the same structure intact. The new site is basically a clone of the old site and I'm trying to recapture the backlinks to the individual pages.  Basically the matching words are always the same and the (. *) word is the only thing that changes.

Comment: You just need to stick the added word to the link (the www.newdomain.com part), and the entire URI from the old site will be inserted where `$1` is. I'm beginning to think the problem really is constructing the right regular expression match.

Comment: The domains are not on the same server.  They are on separate servers and the old domain is empty.  It's just sitting on a hosting account so I could redirect the pages to a new hosting account where the new domain is.  My problem is I don't know how to get that variable to work.  That's the only thing in the actual link that changes.  The words before and after it do not change.

Comment: LOL this worked RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1  I'm so stupid I didn't think it would be that simple.  Will that funnel PR to the new pages?

Comment: oh wait it didn't work right.  It leaves off the different word added to the link structure.  It looks like the link I used may have been cached from a previous test I just did of a straight 301 redirect to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: You definitely want to use `RedirectMatch`, but like I mentioned, you need to build the right regexp match. If you want old.com/a.html to redirect to new.com/pages/a.html, then you want `RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/pages/$1`. Not knowing what this different word is, you'll have to come up with the regexp.